# Docker container Network connection between different host

Tags: networking, routes

I installed docker on two hosts (Virtual Machines). I'd like to make the containers on different host to be able to connect each other.

Here's VM1's and VM2's ifconfig output:

VM1

```
bridge0 : inet addr:172.17.52.1  Bcast:172.17.52.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
docker0 : inet addr:172.17.42.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
eth0 : inet addr:192.168.122.129  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

VM2

```
bridge0 : inet addr:172.17.53.1  Bcast:172.17.53.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
docker0 : inet addr:172.17.42.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
eth0 : inet addr:192.168.122.77  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

`bridge` is used for the container. I have made some network configurations:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.52.0/24 ! -d 172.17.0.0/16 -j MASQUERADE (on VM1)
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.53.0/24 ! -d 172.17.0.0/16 -j MASQUERADE (on VM2)
route add -net 172.17.52.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.122.129 (on VM2)
route add -net 172.17.53.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.122.77 (on VM1)
```

I get no output when a container pings another container

```
(172.17.52.X ping 172.17.53.X)
```

VM1 can ping VM2 successfully. The container on VM1 can also ping VM2 successfully, but I get no output when the container on VM1 pings the container on VM2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One very easy way to achieve this would be by using [Weave](https://github.com/zettio/weave).

You can install it with:

```
sudo wget -O /usr/local/bin/weave \
  https://github.com/zettio/weave/releases/download/latest_release/weave
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/weave
```

#### VM1

```
sudo weave launch
C=$(sudo weave run 10.2.1.1/24 -t -i busybox)
```

#### VM2

```
sudo weave launch 192.168.122.129
C=$(sudo weave run 10.2.1.2/24 -t -i busybox)
docker exec $C ping -c 3 10.2.1.1/24
```

You have just create a virtual network with containers. The beauty is that these VMs can be anywhere, as long as at least one of them has public IP with port 6783 open.

You can even enable [NaCL crypto](http://zettio.github.io/weave/how-it-works.html#crypto) by running `weave launch -password "<MySecret>"` or (exporting `WEAVE_PASSWORD="<MySecret>"` prior to `weave launch`).

Comment: _Disclamer: I am part of the Weave team._