# Ignite Docker cluster without network mode

Tags: docker, ignite, nat

I am trying to setup a two server nodes Apache Ignite cluster, based on Docker containers hosted by two different hosts.

After several tries, the only way I found to have nodes communicating was using "--net=host".

But we are using user namespaces on these hosts, so it's not a solution I can deploy.

Is there some workaround ? I have read things about BasicAddressResolver but no results so far. Maybe it's not a right way.

And overlay networks seem a bit cumbersome for our needs.

Thanks for any help, maybe just a working config file I could adapt.

Regards

BAD
docker run -v "/tmp/apache_ignite_node.xml:/opt/ignite/apache-ignite/config/default-config.xml" -p "10800:10800" -p "11211:11211" -p "47100-47199:47100-47199" -p "47500-47599:47500-47599" -p "49112:49112" apacheignite/ignite:latest

WORKS
docker run --net=host -v "/tmp/apache_ignite_node.xml:/opt/ignite/apache-ignite/config/default-config.xml" -p "10800:10800" -p "11211:11211" -p "47100-47199:47100-47199" -p "47500-47599:47500-47599" -p "49112:49112" apacheignite/ignite:latest

(of course I could remove the ports exposition)

Answer (score 0):

"For communication among containers running on different Docker daemon hosts, you can either manage routing at the OS level, or you can use an overlay network." ([source](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/))

Routing at the OS level I assume means `--net=host`. So, according to Docker, the answer is the overlay network. It looks like [other options are available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28924243/docker-container-network-connection-between-different-host), but that would need extra software.

Comment: But if I expose the required ports using the default syntax above (bridge mode and exposed ports), the other host can reach them, as long as the right firewall rules have been set :
echo "10800 11211 47100 47500" | xargs nc -vz 10.17.10.56
Connection to 10.17.10.56 10800 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
Connection to 10.17.10.56 11211 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
Connection to 10.17.10.56 47100 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
Connection to 10.17.10.56 47500 port [tcp/*] succeeded!

Comment: Or with a very dumb and simple example : docker run -p"443:80" nginx

I can get the index page from the other host : curl -I 10.17.10.56:443
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.23.2
Date: Wed, 30 Nov 2022 16:07:53 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 615
Last-Modified: Wed, 19 Oct 2022 07:56:21 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "634fada5-267"
Accept-Ranges: bytes



So I am now wondering what's wrong with Ignite. Are the communication procotols unable to deal with any kind of NAT ?

Comment: You _can_ use a BasicAddressResolver, but generally it’s more trouble than it’s worth. Best just to have a network where each node can directly resolve every other node. (That’s why nginx works and Ignite doesn’t. Nginx is not a cluster.) And for this situation Docker recommends an overlay network.

Comment: So if I add something like this, it could work ?

<property name="addressResolver">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.BasicAddressResolver">
            <constructor-arg>
                <map>
                    <entry key="INTERNAL_CONTAINER_IP" value="EXTERNAL_HOST_IP"/>
                </map>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </property>

I would just need to put a static IP address for the Ignite container.